# How to call a function from a function called from a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my HTML page:

```
<td ng-repeat="col in input_columns" droppable="true" drop-fn="drop" drop-index="$index" drop-data="col" title="" ng-click="openDialog($event,$index)" tempValue="">&lt;enter data&gt; {{col}} - {{$index}}</td>
```

This is my dragAndDrop.js

```
var app= angular.module('rulesApp');
  app.directive('droppable', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      //scope: {dropData: '=dropData',dropIndex: '=dropIndex'},
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element[0].addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
              //var attr=attrs;
          //var s=scope;
          var f=scope[attrs.dropFn];
         // debugger
          f(e,scope[attrs.dropData],scope[attrs.dropIndex]);//line no. 14
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();

        });
        element[0].addEventListener('dragover', scope.handleDragOver, false);
        element[0].addEventListener('openDialog1', scope.openDialog1, false);
      }
    }
  })
```

This is my controller.js

```
$scope.drop=  function (ev,item,indx) {
        ev.preventDefault();
//some code here
if(true){
            ev.target.innerHTML = data;

            $scope.openDialog1(ev,indx);//error
}
}
$scope.openDialog1 = function($event,item,$index) {
//some code here
}
```

I want to call a function openDialog1 from drop method, which is being called through directive. But I am getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $scope.openDialog1 is not a function$scope.drop @ controllers.js:1589(anonymous function) @ dragAndDrop.js:14.
```

Can anyone please help what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$scope.openDialog1` is defined after it's being called.

In Javascript, unlike actual functions, object properties are **not** hoisted (even if they are assigned to functions); as such you'll need to move the property's initialisation before it's called:

```
$scope.openDialog1 = function($event,item,$index) {
    //some code here
};

$scope.drop = function (ev,item,indx) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    //some code here
    if(true){
        ev.target.innerHTML = data;
        $scope.openDialog1(ev,indx);//error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each item/iteration, ng-repeat creates a new scope.  Because your directive is inside of a child scope, if you want to call $scope.openDialog1, you will have to use $scope.**$parent**.openDialog1().